# How to read a full node with XMLTextReader?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
    <ConfigDatas>
        <ArrayOfConfigData xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BTTest.Models">
            <ConfigData>
                <id>4</id>
                <ip>111111</ip>
                <port>34</port>
            </ConfigData>
            <ConfigData>
                <id>0</id>
                <ip>222222</ip>
                <port i:nil="true" />
            </ConfigData>
        </ArrayOfConfigData>
    </ConfigDatas>
    <OtherTypeDatas>
        <ArrayOfConfigData ...>
            ....
        </ArrayOfConfigData>
    <OtherTypeDatas>
</Data>
```

I would like to parse the xml, getting ConfigDatas and OtherTypeDatas nodes (I can do this just with read), but then when I get for example ConfigDatas node be able to read all ArrayOfConfigData Node text at once. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XmlTextReader is designed to iterate through an XML document.  This is very memory efficient, as you do not create an in-memory representation of the whole document at once.  If you have very large XML documents, it is essential to process them in this manner.

If you want to have the whole XML loaded so that you can e.g. use XPath queries, use [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) or [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) instead, depending on your exact needs.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible; what you need to do is remember the nesting level at the start node (ConfigDatas), then read XML in a loop while nesting level is higher (meaning, while you are below the start node). If there are other parts of the XML that you don't care for, this approach can save you memory, since you will not be loading the entire document which could be too large, if you only need a few smaller nodes.

Comment: You're right. I thought about this method but Won't be using it like this because as Eric stated it is not meant for my use, but what you suggested is a good option if you really need to open a big xml or save mem.